# Clear Recent Repos in Git Gui

Tags: git, git-gui

How can I clear entries in the Git Gui's the recent repositories without deleting those repositories or the `.git` folders within them?

Here is an example:

[image: Recent repositories]

Here is my Git/Git Gui version info:

[image: git-gui version 0.17.GITGUI. git-version 1.8.1.msysgit.1]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The list of recently opened repositories is stored in the config as *gui.recentrepos*.

Visit https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2114111/where-does-git-config-global-get-written-to for more info about where config files are stored.

For example: in my `%HOMEPATH%` folder file `.gitconfig` (msysGit 1.8.1):

```
[gui]
     recentrepo = C:/one
     recentrepo = C:/two
```

And in `C:\Program files\Git\etc\gitconfig` there are no *gui.recentrepo* setting, global settings only.

Comment: I found the `.gitconfig` file under my C:\Users\username folder, but it had different entries from what I see in the UI. Are there other config files that trump this one?

Comment: Find `.gitconfig` in msysgit installation directory, such as `C:\Program files\msysgit` or so

Comment: Can you add code for what the config file might look like to help others?

Comment: In my case, the file was under `%HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH%`, which is where the shortcut's start in parameter was set to.

Comment: edited my answer

Comment: How i can clear clear recent repos on Linux Ubuntu 14.04?

Answer (score 8):

Open Git Bash and try:

```
git config --global --unset-all gui.recentrepo
```